# How to fetch all the table name from Azure's database using php pdo and it is not like the normal Sql server?

Tags: php, sql-server, azure, pdo

I tried all other queries mention in this forum but none worked on Azure database.
my query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='dbName';
```

but it didn't work. I tried almost every stackoverflow solution.
Please help to query all table from azure database.
thanks.

my code:

```
<?php   

try {

    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=tcp:sahilpaudel.database.windows.net,1433 ;Database=dbname", "usernam", "password");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $query = $conn->prepare('SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='dbName'');
    $query->execute();

    while($rows = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo $rows['TABLE_NAME'];
    }
}
 catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

?>

Comment: Azure is not a database, it is Microsoft's cloud. Do you have the right connection to SQL-Server?

Comment: i mean on database that is in azure.

Comment: Without seeing your connection or your error checking it would be impossible for us to know what problems you're exoeriencing.

Comment: Well, for one, your question indicates you're using MSSQL, so `information_schema` isn't going to exist.

Comment: when i used `SHOW TABLES` it gives stored procedure 'SHOW' does not exist.

Comment: so help me to get the right query to get all the table as `SHOW TABLES` isn't working and nor the others. please suggest.